# What CMYK values should I use for the brightest highlights in an image?

Tags: color, images, cmyk, white, highlights

I usually set the whitest part of the image to C5 M4 Y4 K0, but this is making some product shots of glassware (ie wine glasses, glass trophies) look grey.

Does anyone use a different CMYK mix for the highlights? I don't want there to be no colour in the white area as it will look blown out.

Comment: What software are you using? What settings?

Comment: I would think you simply need to choose cool or warm highlights then eliminate either the M&Y or the C.

Comment: Ideally, work with your printer on this. They may have some presets for your images based on the type of image and how it's bring printed. A larger printer might even handle all of this for you in their prepress department.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I'm using Photoshop to adjust the image via levels or curves adjustment.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this:

1. Used the Dodge tools (midtones) to remove any grey in the glass area
2. Curve adjustment to remove any grey from the thicker parts of the glass, ie sides and bottom of the glass
3. Eyedropper on the normal glass area in the middle and Levels adjustment to make this 5/4/4/0
4. Added a line of reflection in the left of the glass and made this a lighter, ie a spectacular highlight with 0/0/0/0 on some images

I did find a mention of making this 3/2/2/0 as well via a printer's website, but I'm going to keep with my mix.

Here's a before and after:
[image: Colour corrected before and after]

Comment: I'm wondering if the actual problem is that your image lacked specular highlights (which you'd expect to always be white)

Answer (score 1):

I usually set whitest part by re-defining the default values for Curves white point eyedropper. Just double click on the eyedropper icon and you're able to enter your own values. You will be able to click on the white area of the image and the CMYK values will be set to the necessary ones with just one click.

If the image looks gray we can correct it by of midtones (as on the picture below). It's RGB file, so the curve should go down for CMYK.

[image: Curves]